# Corrupted inetpub\history config file For Windows 10

Tags: windows

Is there a default notepad I can use to copy paste over my corrupted one? The notepad file I have does not show in `(%SystemDrive%\inetpub\history)` nor does the `configHistory` show either. I get multiple (like 42) Event ID 9010 errors because this option doesn't even show in my notepad. From what I understand the following should resemble this:

In notepad, search for the configHistory section under system.applicationHost. The contents should resemble the following:

```
<system.applicationHost>
    <configHistory enabled="true" path="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\history" maxHistories="10" period="00:02:00" />

</system.applicationHost>
```

I have spend hrs and searched every line in my notepad and there is nothing even close. I am loath to just 'stick it in there' not being sure exactly where it goes or what caused it to be wrong in the first place. Excuse my ignorance. I have use the following CMD prompts to bring the notepad up to relate where I'm at and what I'm doing they are:-

View the configHistory section by using notepad
To view the configHistory section by using notepad:
Open an elevated Command Prompt window.
Click Start, point to All Programs, click Accessories, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as administrator.
Type: `cd %Windir%\system32\inetsrv\config`
Type: `notepad ApplicationHost.config`

If someone could point me to where I may get a good notepad config it would make my day. I have run `sfc /scannow` but it doesn't seem to effect this. I am also wondering if the only way to correct it is to do a Windows 10 Repair.

Comment: From the first paragraph at the end where it says the following should resemble this:               <system.applicationHost>
    <configHistory enabled="true" path="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\history" maxHistories="10" period="00:02:00" />
       </system.applicationHost> the above needs to be inserted from the f

Comment: for some reason the OP was edited before I even posted it making it very convoluted.